# UIActivityController does not report the text and image when sharing on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have this simple piece of code to display a sharing dialog for a number of social avenues:

```
let text = String(format:NSLocalizedString("I %@ with the Dhammapada verse \"%@\"", comment:"$ to be composed with $$"), part, verse)
let url = URL(string:"http://www.ipuja.net")
let image = buddhanetImage.image ?? UIImage(named:"Icon-72")
let shareController=UIActivityViewController(activityItems:[text, url!, image!], applicationActivities:nil)
shareController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .pad){
    shareController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.buddhanetImage;
    }
self.present(shareController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Yet the tool woks fine for Google and Twitter, but when I try to share the contents on Facebook, just the url is shown without either text of image.
I checked that doing the thing on Photos and other other third party apps allows to display the full content even for Facebook, so what is missing in my code for that to work?

Answer (score 0):

The `URL` will override the `text` and `image` when sharing to Facebook from a third-party application. Remove the `URL` and the `image` and `text` will appear. Also, if you have multiple hashtags in your `text`, only the first hashtag will be applied.

Prior to iOS 9, prefilling the Facebook share dialog with `text`, `image`, and `URL` was possible. Once iOS 9 was released, prefilling any fields when sharing to Facebook was not possible at all. Sometime around iOS 9.3 they reenabled prefilling fields, but prefilling **all** the fields is not possible.

Comment: That is not good as the url is there for marketing purposes. Anyway I shall try that, manually entering the URL, waiting for the thing to eventually work for all the fields automatically.

Comment: I removed the url and in fact now the image shows, but the text is still missing.